# Further group objects  in a many to many relation 

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a blog model with m2m relationship with a tag object.I want each blog to have  multiple sets of tags say [tagset1,tagset2......]. When user submits some sets of tags[usertagset1,usertagset2.....] to retrieve blogs, I have to return all blogs with 
usertagset being subset of blog's tagset.

I am not sure of best way to go about it with minimum no. of sql queries.
Should I create a new model that holds the info of blog's tagsets and then have the blog model an m2m relation with this new model?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter out tags one by one:

```
user_tags = [tag1, tag2, ... tagn]
blogs = Blogs.objects.all()
for tag in user_tags:
    blogs = blogs.filter(tags=tag) # assuming 'tags' is your M2M field name
```

Each filter() will narrow your search until only blogs having all specified tags are remaining. Since Django's QuerySets are lazy and can be combined, this will result in a single SQL query.